# SD Card random bit error on reading, no failure

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sd-card

I have a deployment of some 20 Raspberry Pis with Kingston 16 GB Micro SD HC Class 10 U1 cards in them, all cloned from identical customised Raspbian image. Small text on the card says:

`SDC10B2/16GB
31608-010-A00LF
TAIWAN`

This setup has been running around 6 months now and around 10 of the cards have broken down with some weird characteristics.

First cards broke down within **weeks** of deployment. Admittedly there was some extensive logging at that time. Also some cards have broken down without application logging turned on – only regular Raspbian logging. Even with the high logging the cards should have lasted few years when taking into account write cycles wear.

I happened to be logged into some raspi at the time this problem occured and what I noticed:

- system binaries, like `vim` and `sudo` would fail to load shared libs (`.so` files)
- My own source code would have random byte errors in it when viewed in editor
- redownloading my source and writing to files would fix it for these files, for the time being.

I now went over all of the failed cards and noticed that they all are accessible and readable on my Mac. I wrote a script to checksum all files in the `/boot` partition 10 times, measured the time and counted different checksums.

On a normal working card it would take on average 0.3 seconds every iteration and of course return identical checksum every time.

But on these failed cards, the times are much higher – 7 to 20 seconds per iteration and would return **different checksum** on every run for some of the files. The errors do not happen to all of the files, but mostly the same files on all the cards (last files in alphabetical order).

Example run (the number behind filename is the count of different checksums):

[image]

Repeated runs on one of the cards that gives error on 1 file only, would result anywhere between 4-10 different checksums. Following is a take of one that had 5 checksums, in order of appearance:

`["9c91d29a602ac91b6db803aff2589099", "4c5e5e134bdd74c385b3ad69b28ea724", "9c91d29a602ac91b6db803aff2589099", "9c91d29a602ac91b6db803aff2589099", "9c91d29a602ac91b6db803aff2589099", "4ea7e6b69623405081f4db7a80d62bb4", "5a9d78acb7eefbc9839bab3fcc3f7599", "9c91d29a602ac91b6db803aff2589099", "1d6f8ad8a528e0abae0f00032eeb712b", "9c91d29a602ac91b6db803aff2589099"]`

As seen – one checksum could be repeated even after giving different results in between.

*To recap:* the filesystem is accessible, card seems to function properly, but repeated reading from files gives different results, rendering it unusable. Seems as if some blocks on the card just return garbage when read.

**QUESTION 1**: Is such a corruption related to write wear on the card and if so, is there any Raspberry distro out there optimised for long-term, low write usage?

**QUESTION 2**: Is this due to cheap cards and I should buy better ones? Which ones?